# How to return number of opened ticket type bug

Tags: jira, jql

Is their any function in Jira using `JQL` to return a number of opened ticket and issue type Bug?

```
labels = ABCD AND Type!= Bug AND status !="In Progress"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this JQL

```
Project = "Project name" AND labels = ABCD AND Type= Bug AND status ="In Progress"
```

Query Result = Number of Bugs which are in status "In Progress"

Note: Status "in-Progress" and "To-Do" can mean that the issue is in Open state.
The definition of Status is completely project specific and can be controlled by the Jira Admin. (general status - To do, In-progress and done)

Comment: That query will return a list of Tickets, but i am looking for a query that return a number of tickets ( How many Tickets , number type of integer ). e.g.: 10

Comment: To my understanding JQL when used in the Jira UI tool always gives u the list of required results. to get a result as a number , i am not sure if you can get with the Built in widgets in Jira.!? -- like you have a widget to show the remaining number of sprint days..